# How to get Formated JSON output in CakePHP controller

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, cakephp-2.0

What should i do to convert my **JSON** output.
So that it could be easily iterate using J Query.

I am using **CakePHP** controller to generate **JSON** after **MySql** Query.

Is there any Help in CakePHP without Trick ?

I am getting Output as

**OUTPUT In View**

```
[{"8":"Young"},{"9":"Child"},{"10":"Old"},{"11":"Large"}]
```

**I need 
Output As**

```
[{ "id":"8", "name": "Young" }, { "id": "9", "name": "Child" }, { "id": "10", "name": "Old" },{ "id":"11", "name": "Large" }]
```

**Controller -> gettype method**

```
 if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
        if(isset($this->request->data['typeid'])){
            $listType= array();
            $arrayOfIds = explode(',',$this->request->data['TypeIds']);
            foreach($arrayOfIds as $TypeId) {
                $listType[] = $this->Type->find('list', array(
                                                    'conditions' => array(
                                                    'Type.id' => $TypeId
                                                ),
                                                'fields' => array('Type.name')
                                            ));
            }
            echo json_encode($listType);
        }
    }
```

**AJAX in View**

```
var dataType = 'typeid='+ typeid+'&TypeIds='+ TypeIds;
var urlToGetType = absUrl+"gettype/";
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    url: urlToGetType,
    data: dataType,
    success: function (resTypeData, status) {
        console.log(resTypeData);                       
    },
    error: function (xhr, desc, err) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Is your JSON coming from PHP?

Comment: yes its coming from PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I figured out why my original solution wouldn't work:  You're calling the 'list' method on find() which generates the output as:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 'displayValue',
    [1] => 'displayValue1',
    [2] => 'displayValue2',
)
```

Use find('all') instead:

```
[ModelName] => Array
    (
        [id] => 83
        [field1] => value1
        [field2] => value2
        [field3] => value3
    )
```

And again set the following:

```
'fields' => array('Type.id', 'Type.name')
```

Here's the CakePHP [Retrieving Your Data Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're close but are tripped by by the oddity of `json_encode`. Let's say you start with your first object as an array in PHP (this is pseudo for the sake of argument)

```
['8'=>'young', '9'=>'child']
```

What you would do is this

```
$newar = [];
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $newar[] = ['id' => $key, 'name' => $val];
}
echo json_encode($newar);
```

Remember that PHP allows associative arrays, while JS does not. So associative PHP arrays become JS objects instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with CakePHP, but from a strictly PHP stand point you could just iterate through it.

```
$string = '[{"8":"Young"},{"9":"Child"},{"10":"Old"},{"11":"Large"}]';

foreach (json_decode($string) as $obj) {
  foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    $temp[] = array(
      'id'   => $key,
      'name' => $value
    );
  }
}

echo "<pre><code>";
print_r(json_encode($temp));
echo "</code></pre>";
```

I'm sure you must be able to tweak your MySQL Query. I'm looking into that.

### edit

you should most likely put it here:

```
foreach($arrayOfIds as $TypeId) {
  $listType[] = $this->Type->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array(
      'Type.id' => $TypeId
    ),
    'fields' => array('Type.name')
  ));
}
foreach ($listType as $obj) {
  foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    $newListType[] = array(
      'id'   => $key,
      'name' => $value
    );
  }
}

echo json_encode($newListType);
```

The best I can do from reading the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list) without a testing environment.

From the docs:

> By default, the primary key for the model is used for the key, and the display field (which can be configured using the model attribute [displayField](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#model-displayfield)) is used for the value.

Answer (score 1):

Changing it from a `find('list'` to `find('all'` will give you named fields.